# how to get value from Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url:'abc/abc/abc',
   success:  function(response){
      var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      var value=result.roles;
   }
});
```

How can I get "value=result.roles" from ext.ajax.request?

I am trying to use an action.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url:'abc/abc/abc',
   success: function(response){
      var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      var value=result.roles;
      getValue(value);                    
   }
});

function getValue(value) {
   return value;
};
```

But I still can't get the value.

How can I do this?

Comment: What isn't working? That code should work for you assuming response is valid and can be decoded as JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You need to use this:

```
success: function ( result, request ) {
                      var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                      var resultMessage = jsonData.data.result;
                     fn_AKExt(resultMessage, ‘Success’);
               },
failure: function ( result, request ) {
                   var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                  var resultMessage = jsonData.data.result;
                  fn_AKExt(resultMessage, ‘Error’);
}
```

Check out [How To Use Ext.Ajax.Request With Response Text](http://akdora.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/how-to-use-extajaxrequest-with-response-text/) for more details.

Comment: Pointless decoding the data on a failure IMHO.

Comment: Yes, but after searching. I took the specific one. And also linked to the original article.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the AJAX request is asynchronous.  That's why we do not get the value out of the request. If we set  async:false, then we can get the value.

```
var cnt;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    async:false,
    url: '...',
    params: {},
    success: function (response) {
        var cnt= Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    }
});
return cnt;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. This will help other users to quickly understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   async: false, 
   type: "GET",
   url :"url", 
   data :"",  
   success:(data){ 
      functionOutSideAjax(parameter);   
   }  
});

functionOutSideAjax(var){  
  useThisVar = parameter;  
}
```

Create your function() outside the ajax response then pass the required values from your ajax response and then you can use "useThisVar" where ever you want in javascript file ..

Comment: Right, if only the question was related to jQuery ...  It's about ExtJS/Sencha :-)